# How to understand LocalVariableTable area in javap output

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

Source code:

```
public class Example {
   public int plus(int a){
     int b = 1;
     return a + b;
   }
 }
```

Deassemble result of previous file's class:

```
public int plus(int);
  Code:
   Stack=2, Locals=3, Args_size=2
   0:   iconst_1
   1:   istore_2
   2:   iload_1
   3:   iload_2
   4:   iadd
   5:   ireturn
  LineNumberTable:
   line 5: 0
   line 6: 2

  LocalVariableTable:
   Start  Length  Slot  Name     Signature
   0      6       0     this     LExample;
   0      6       1     a        I
   2      4       2     b        I
```

My question is how to understand the following area, what does the `Length`, `Slot` mean here:

```
  LocalVariableTable:
   Start  Length  Slot  Name     Signature
   0      6       0     this     LExample;
   0      6       1     a        I
   2      4       2     b        I
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [the specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html#5956) :

Start is the line at which the variable is defined in the bytecode, and length the number of lines of byte codes for which it is defined. So start to length defines the scope of the variable. 
I guess the Slot corresponds to the index, which is itself roughly 0 for the first variable, 1 for the second, 2 for the third and so on (plus added offset in the case of doubles/longs).